# how to create a vector of tuples and append to it in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, cout

I am trying to create a vector of tuples, which I can add to throughout the code. I'm super new to C++, so I am just trying a toy example of create a vector of tuples and adding one element to it. My code looks like this:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>> coords;
coords.push_back(<std:tuple<4,4>>);
cout << coords <<endl;
```

The vector is named `coords`, and I am trying to add a tuple (4,4) to it, then print the vector.

I get this error when compiling...

```
RPPG.cpp:32:1: error: unknown type name 'coords'
coords.push_back(<std:tuple<4,4>>);
^
RPPG.cpp:32:7: error: cannot use dot operator on a type
coords.push_back(<std:tuple<4,4>>);
      ^
RPPG.cpp:33:1: error: unknown type name 'cout'
cout << coords <<endl;
^
RPPG.cpp:33:6: error: expected unqualified-id
cout << coords <<endl;
```

I'm confused, what does this mean? It compiles if I just create the vector and dont append/print. Why are these failing?

Comment: That's neither how you construct a tuple, nor how you print the contents of a vector. Also this is not a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

This is fantasy syntax:

```
coords.push_back(<std:tuple<4,4>>);
```

`std::tuple<int,int>` is the type of the vectors elements. To create an instance of that type and push it to the vector you can write this:

```
coords.push_back(std::tuple<int,int>{4,4});
```

Or create the instance in place via:

```
coords.emplace_back(4,4);
```

*PS*: `cout << coords <<endl;` There is no predefined way to print a `std::vector<std::tuple<int,int>>`. You can write a loop and print the individual tuple elements.

*PPS*: The error you posted is not from the code you posted. I took the liberty to ignore errors that are not related to the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks. I changed my `push_back` code to what you recommended and dropped the `cout` code for now. I still get the error `error: unknown type name 'coords'`. I thought I had the syntax right to create/name my vector as `coords`?

Comment: @connor449 the error `unknown type name 'coords'` is from code you did not include in your post. I answered only based on the code you posted. Please read about [mcve] and next time please make sure the code you post is the one that creates the error you want to fix